# QFile takes more than one parameter?

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

i have a class:

```
Class MyClass
{
    void myMember();
    ///code etc
    private:
        QFile fileMBox; 
}
```

and in the class' member i try to use:

```
void MyClass::myMember()
{
    fileMBox ("myFile.txt");
}
```

and i get an error saying:  "error: C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments" but the docs say to use:

```
QFile file("in.txt");
```

what am i doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you brought up is a constructor. It's called when the object is actually made, not later. You're acting like the object is a functor, "calling" the object after it's made.

To utilize the constructor, you can initialize your member with the file name:

```
MyClass::MyClass() : fileMBox ("myFile.txt") {}
```

However, not having used Qt, I don't know if that will open it or not. If it does open it, use the below instead:

```
MyClass::MyClass() {
    fileMBox.setFileName ("myFile.txt");
}
```

Now your function just needs to open it, use it, and close it each time:

```
void MyClass::myMember() {
    if (!fileMBox.open (QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        //handle error

    //read file and do whatever

    fileMBox.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what I'm trying to do is actually read text from a file:

The following example reads a text file line by line:

    QFile file("in.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
         return;

    while (!file.atEnd()) {
         QByteArray line = file.readLine();
         process_line(line);
    }

Comment: @Laserbeak43, Do you want the file to be open when an object of your class is made, or have all of this happen when you call that function?

Comment: I want to have it happen when i call the function, since the file can be updated at any time. 
P.S.
sorry, the formatting doesn't seem to work the way that i thought for replies..

Comment: @Laserbeak43, That should do fine in your other function.

Comment: that did it!!! thank you very much!!! It was so simple but my code is so crowded that i couldn't see it. I have to build some good coding habits.

Comment: @Laserbeak43, I updated it again. It's almost the same, but if the constructor doesn't open it, you can replace the `setFileName` call with something better.

Comment: ah, i know why...the .setFileName() part isnt mentioned in the documentation...at least not in the example given... :(